# Implode / Explode PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to manipulate an `$array:`

```
Array ([0] => General [1] => Custom Title)
```

Using Implode, I can get the `$array` into individual pieces seperated by a space:

```
<?php $pieces = implode(" ", $array); ?>
```

Output:

```
General Custom Title
```

However, if the array pieces are two words, it doesn't work as I would prefer the output to be:

```
General Custom-Title
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You could just do a `str_replace` on the hyphen and replace it with ' '.

Comment: First iterate through the array and swap out spaces with dashes. Then use implode.

Comment: you can't to escape separators with implode. It has very simple implementation. Do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace spaces with hyphens, before you implode.

```
foreach ($arr as $idx => $val) {
    $arr[$idx] = str_replace(" ", "-", $val);
}
$pieces = implode(" ", $arr);
```

Comment: Using `array_map()` the footprint should be lower than with `foreach()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some string manipulation function for this. I suggest a combination of `str_replace` with either `array_walk` (or `array_map`) or a simple `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $myArray[$key] = str_replace(' ' , '-', $value);
}
$output = implode(' ', $myArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = array('Hallo X', 'Hallo Y');

echo implode(' ', (array_map(function($e) { return str_replace(' ', '-', $e); }, $x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner. The flaw is that you may have %% in the elements of your array, but I doubt that.

`$pieces = str_replace('%%', ' ', str_replace(' ', '-', implode('%%', $array)));`